# stop event propagation for Vaadin Flow buttons

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a Vaadin 23 application where I have a `Div` element with a `Button` in it (among other content) and a click listener added to it, as well as to the button:

```
Button button = new Button();
button.addClickListener(event -> { ... });

Div wrapper = new Div(button);
wrapper.addClickListener(event -> { ... });
```

The problem is that both listeners are firing when the button is clicked.

How can I make sure that only the button click listener is fired in that case?  I want the click listener on the `Div` to fire when I click anywhere inside the `Div` except on the button.

Alternatively, if I could detect in the click listener on the `Div` that the click was actually on the button, I could simply ignore it.  But I don't see how to do that either.

This is a port from a Vaadin 8 app where it was working correctly.  The wrapper `Div` in that case was a `CssLayout` with a `LayoutClickListener` added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [highly voted](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/1363) issue for adding this feature to Vaadin Flow. Different workarounds are also described in the issue.

In your case, I think the workaround would look like this:

```
button.getElement().addEventListener("click", ignore -> {}).addEventData("event.stopPropagation()");
```

Comment: Thanks that works.  Indeed, when adding a server-side event listener it should always be an option to stop propagation.  I'm wondering if that shouldn't even be the default for button click listeners.

Comment: It could be the default if there would be a way of disabling the default, but probably better to have it as it is now when the configurability isn't there but a workaround exists.